# Constants is growing. Any other alternative

Tags: java

We are working in java applications. We are defining huge constants for our applicable. It grows heavily large.

I saw in several enterprise applications and it is unavoidable and they are creating Constants.java

Most of the constants are even generic which can be used in any project.

Example as follows

```
1. Id
2. created date
3. created time
4. start date
5. end date
```

etc.,

Is there a way to cut down the constants via any third party library which has inbuilt huge constants ???

Why Java doesn't have own constants to standardize all J2EE applications ???

Says if the primary key should be named as "primary key" or "id" or "key" then it would be a standard practice for all and easy for maintenance by any J2EE developer.

Thanks.

Comment: I will recommend you to refine your question. The last part can lead to discussions about the philosophy of the software instead of a concrete answer.

Comment: The problem you are facing is specific but your `Why Java doesn't have own constants to standardize all J2EE applications ???
 `question is very generic. Please focus on the problem rather on why doesn't java provide this.

For your use. you can create your own utility.
You can create a constant class and refer to the value required. it will remain the same. where ever you want a constant it has to be called or accessed via some class or library.

Comment: *"Says if the primary key should be named as "primary key" or "id" or "key""* - But my system doesn't use any of those identifiers and it's your software that wants to connect to it

Comment: I think I know what you're getting at. But it is up to you as a company to set your own standards - and what works for you might not work for me, hence, you have to do your own legwork here.